# Build nested tree-like dict from an array of dicts with children

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, tree

I have an array of dicts retrieved from a web API. Each dict has a `name`, `description`, 'parent', and `children` key. The `children` key has an array of dicts as it value. For the sake of clarity, here is a dummy example:

```
[
  {'name': 'top_parent', 'description': None, 'parent': None,
   'children': [{'name': 'child_one'},
                {'name': 'child_two'}]},
  {'name': 'child_one', 'description': None, 'parent': 'top_parent',
   'children': []},
  {'name': 'child_two', 'description': None, 'parent': 'top_parent',
   'children': [{'name': 'grand_child'}]},
  {'name': 'grand_child', 'description': None, 'parent': 'child_two',
   'children': []}
]
```

Every item in in the array. An item could be the top-most parent, and thus not exist in any of the `children` arrays. An item could be both a child and a parent. Or an item could only be a child (have no children of its own).

So, in a tree structure, you'd have something like this:

```
top_parent
  child_one
  child_two
    grand_child
```

In this contrived and simplified example `top_parent` is a parent but not a child; `child_one` is a child but not a parent; `child_two` is a parent and a child; and `grand_child` is a child but not a parent. This covers every possible state.

What I want is to be able to iterate over the array of dicts 1 time and generate a nested dict that properly represents the tree structure (however, it 1 time is impossible, the most efficient way possible). So, in this example, I would get a dict that looked like this:

```
{
  'top_parent': {
    'child_one': {},
    'child_two': {
      'grand_child': {}
    }
  }    
}
```

Strictly speaking, it is not necessary to have item's without children to not be keys, but that is preferable.

Comment: And you want to ignore the names and descriptions in your final dictionary?

Comment: They *can* be ignored, but they need not. The key goal is the nested dictionary that properly represents the objects' parent-child relationship.

Comment: Are names guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: Yes. Names will be unique. This is guaranteed by the web service.

Comment: BFS or DFS would work fine I guess. Each node will be visited just once and you can store the result in the dict the way you like.

Comment: Do you really need just one loop, or do you need order O(N)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fourth edit, showing three versions, cleaned up a bit.  First version works top-down and returns None, as you requested, but essentially loops through the top level array 3 times.  The next version only loops through it once, but returns empty dicts instead of None.

The final version works bottom up and is very clean.  It can return empty dicts with a single loop, or None with additional looping:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_array = [
  {'name': 'top_parent', 'description': None, 'parent': None,
   'children': [{'name': 'child_one'},
                {'name': 'child_two'}]},
  {'name': 'child_one', 'description': None, 'parent': 'top_parent',
   'children': []},
  {'name': 'child_two', 'description': None, 'parent': 'top_parent',
   'children': [{'name': 'grand_child'}]},
  {'name': 'grand_child', 'description': None, 'parent': 'child_two',
   'children': []}
]

def build_nest_None(my_array):
    childmap = [(d['name'], set(x['name'] for x in d['children']) or None)
                for d in my_array]
    all_dicts = dict((name, kids and {}) for (name, kids) in childmap)
    results = all_dicts.copy()
    for (name, kids) in ((x, y) for x, y in childmap if y is not None):
        all_dicts[name].update((kid, results.pop(kid)) for kid in kids)
    return results

def build_nest_empty(my_array):
    all_children = set()
    all_dicts = defaultdict(dict)
    for d in my_array:
        children = set(x['name'] for x in d['children'])
        all_dicts[d['name']].update((x, all_dicts[x]) for x in children)
        all_children.update(children)
    top_name, = set(all_dicts) - all_children
    return {top_name: all_dicts[top_name]}


def build_bottom_up(my_array, use_None=False):
    all_dicts = defaultdict(dict)
    for d in my_array:
        name = d['name']
        all_dicts[d['parent']][name] = all_dicts[name]

    if use_None:
        for d in all_dicts.values():
            for x, y in d.items():
                if not y:
                    d[x] = None

    return all_dicts[None]

print(build_nest_None(my_array))
print(build_nest_empty(my_array))
print(build_bottom_up(my_array, True))
print(build_bottom_up(my_array))
```

Results in:

```
{'top_parent': {'child_one': None, 'child_two': {'grand_child': None}}}
{'top_parent': {'child_one': {}, 'child_two': {'grand_child': {}}}}
{'top_parent': {'child_one': None, 'child_two': {'grand_child': None}}}
{'top_parent': {'child_one': {}, 'child_two': {'grand_child': {}}}}
```

Comment: The `build_bottom_up()` function, without the need for using `None`, is (you're right) the cleanest. Obviously, the "magic" is happening in the last line inside the `for` loop. I'd love to hear you walk through what precisely is happening there.

Comment: Actually, the "magic" is inside defaultdict.  Since I passed in `dict` as the constructor for all_dicts values, on any index operation where a regular dict would have given a KeyError, the defaultdict will construct a new default object (an empty dict) and add it to the dictionary.

This behavior means that it doesn't matter whether the parent object or the child object is encountered first -- in either case, dicts will be constructed as necessary, and then the same dict will be available and used when the other object is encountered.  If this isn't clear, I'll try again...

Comment: I see now that 6502 has edited his answer to add an option using a defaultdict, which makes it basically be the same as this answer.  The only differences between that and this are that (a) he makes things a bit more explicit; and (b) he doesn't store the top dict in the defaultdict.  Both of these features might make his code a bit easier to understand and follow, but they both reduce performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a lazy mapping from names to nodes and then rebuild the hierarchy by processing just the `parent` link (I'm assuming data is correct, so if `A` is marked as the parent of `B` **iff** `B` is listed among the children of `A`).

```
nmap = {}
for n in nodes:
    name = n["name"]
    parent = n["parent"]
    try:
        # Was this node built before?
        me = nmap[name]
    except KeyError:
        # No... create it now
        if n["children"]:
            nmap[name] = me = {}
        else:
            me = None
    if parent:
        try:
            nmap[parent][name] = me
        except KeyError:
            # My parent will follow later
            nmap[parent] = {name: me}
    else:
        root = me
```

The `children` property of the input is used only to know if the element should be stored as a `None` in its parent (because has no children) or if it should be a dictionary because it will have children at the end of the rebuild process. Storing nodes without children as empty dictionaries would simplify the code a bit by avoiding the need of this special case.

Using `collections.defaultdict` the code can also be simplified for the creation of new nodes

```
import collections
nmap = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for n in nodes:
    name = n["name"]
    parent = n["parent"]
    me = nmap[name]
    if parent:
        nmap[parent][name] = me
    else:
        root = me
```

This algorithm is `O(N)` assuming constant-time dictionary access and makes only one pass on the input and requires `O(N)` space for the name->node map  (the space requirement is `O(Nc)` for the original `nochildren->None` version where `Nc` is the number of nodes with children).

Comment: I will edit the question, but `None` is not a required value. So, I'd love to see your simplified version without that constraint.

Answer (score 0):

My stab at it:

```
persons = [\
  {'name': 'top_parent', 'description': None, 'parent': None,\
   'children': [{'name': 'child_one'},\
                {'name': 'child_two'}]},\
  {'name': 'grand_child', 'description': None, 'parent': 'child_two',\
   'children': []},\
  {'name': 'child_two', 'description': None, 'parent': 'top_parent',\
   'children': [{'name': 'grand_child'}]},\
  {'name': 'child_one', 'description': None, 'parent': 'top_parent',\
   'children': []},\
]

def findParent(name,parent,tree,found = False):
    if tree == {}:
        return False
    if parent in tree:
        tree[parent][name] = {}
        return True
    else:
        for p in tree:
            found = findParent(name,parent,tree[p],False) or found
        return found

tree = {}
outOfOrder = []
for person in persons:
    if person['parent'] == None:
        tree[person['name']] = {}
    else:
        if not findParent(person['name'],person['parent'],tree):
            outOfOrder.append(person)
for person in outOfOrder:
    if not findParent(person['name'],person['parent'],tree):
        print 'parent of ' + person['name']  + ' not found
print tree
```

results in:

```
{'top_parent': {'child_two': {'grand_child': {}}, 'child_one': {}}}
```

It also picks up any children whose parent has not been added yet, and then reconciles this at the end.